# SQL Server trigger inserting duplicates

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I'm debugging a data pipeline that consists of several tables and triggers.

We have a table called `Dimension_Date` defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dimension_Date]
(
    [id_date] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [a_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [yoy_date] [date] NOT NULL
)
```

We also have three different tables in which other processes are inserting data (with transactions, although I don't have access to these processes). Each table contains a `Datetime` column (`x_date`) that needs to be inserted in the `Dimension` table only if that datetime doesn't exist already in the `Dimension` table. If it already exists, it shouldn't be inserted.

On each of these tables there is a trigger that, among other things, checks if the datetime exists in the `Dimension` table and if it isn't, inserts the new date. Once all the actions are performed, the content of TABLE_1, 2 and 3 are deleted. The triggers (of tables TABLE_1, 2 and 3) contain the following query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_Date_Trigger] 
ON [dbo].[TABLE_1]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Dimension_Date (a_date, yoy_date)
        SELECT DISTINCT x_date, DateADD(yy, -100, CONVERT(date, x_date)) 
        FROM TABLE_1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id_date FROM Dimension_Date 
                          WHERE a_date = TABLE_1.a_date);

        (...)

        DELETE FROM TABLE_1
END
```

The problem is that these triggers are inserting duplicates in the Dimension table (two different `id_date` for the same `a_date` field), and I can't figure out where the problem is. Could it be that the processes might not be using transactions? Is there anything wrong with the query?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you wanted an `instead of insert` trigger to begin with.

Comment: And if you do want an `AFTER INSERT` where are your referenced to `inserted`?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the suggestion, but would it make any difference (about the duplicates) if I reference `inserted` instead of `TABLE_1`?

Comment: Probably, because you wouldn't try to `INSERT` the entirety of `TABLE_1` into `Dimension_Date` again.

Comment: @Larnu, but I'm deleting the table at the end of the trigger, so it's empty when the new insert is executed.

Comment: @yet_another_programmer Do you guarantee that only one user at a time can insert into the table then?

Comment: @GSerg Yes, there's only one process writing data into that table.